# Getting user information from id_token

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I used `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` in the frontend to get a Google OAuth2 `id_token`. I am trying to use this token to obtain user information in the Django backend. As an experiment, I hardcoded the freshly obtained `id_token` and verified it:

```py
from google.oauth2 import id_token
from google.auth.transport import requests

MY_APP_CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
token = 'a very long id_token'

idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request(), MY_APP_CLIENT_ID)
print(idinfo.keys())
```

Here is the output:

```
dict_keys(['iss', 'azp', 'aud', 'sub', 'at_hash', 'c_hash', 'nbf', 'iat', 'exp', 'jti'])
```

So, `idinfo` does not have the name of the user and his email. What am I missing? How do I obtain those?

**EDIT** After adding the `email` and `profile` scopes in both the manifest file for my extension and the dictionary passed to `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow`, I do get the email address, but still no first or last name of the user.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `id_token` really does not contain this information.
What worked for me is to instead get a `code` from `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` and then follow the steps in the documentation beginning [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect#exchangecode).

Note that the `code` is single-use, so if you encounter an error, obtain another `code` for the next try.

Answer (score 0):

Id token isn't going to give you much user profile info its just there to verify the user and that is given to you with the sub claim.

If you want reliable user profile info then you should to go though the [people api](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest).

## update

userinfo_endpoint can and will give you limited amount of user profile data, however there is no guarantee that the claims will be returned by it every time.  Google recommends using the people api if you want to be 100% sure to get the profile data back every time.

If you chose to use the userinfo endpoint just make sure you do a check for null values so you don't get any errors when the data comes back null.

Comment: Is people API the one I linked to in my reply?

Comment: There you go i added a link

Comment: Then your answer is incorrect, because I obtained profile information from `userinfo_endpoint` listed [here](https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning i beg to differ for your definition of incorrect.    You can use the userinfo endpoint if you like but best practice says to use the people api.   Its not wrong there are just two ways of doing things its up to you which system you go with.

Comment: "If you want user profile info then you need to go though the people api." This sounds like there is only one way and that is inaccurate.

Comment: Sorry for my miss wording I have fixed it to be more clear.